# Using groovy 'super' keyword when referencing properties of a java superclass

Tags: java, groovy

I've inherited a large groovy/java project and I am stumbling upon a usage pattern that just doesn't seem to work, but I can't figure out why.

My predecessor makes frequent use of a java superclass and 
many groovy subclasses. In the subclasses, he has getters that perform a 
lazy initialize and then, through the use of a property, set a value on 
the super class. Unfortunately, this seems to throw a NoSuchFieldError.

I was able to reproduce this in a small test case, given below. 
Essentially, referencing a property as "super.property" is throwing a 
NoSuchFieldError, but referencing it as just "property" works fine.

Here's some Java base classes:

```
public interface Content {
     public String getValue();
}

public class HolderJava {
     private Content _content;
     public Content getContent() { return _content; }
     public void setContent(Content value) { _content = value; }
}
```

And here are some groovy classes that extend them:

```
class ContentGroovy implements Content {
     def     value
     public String getValue() {
         value
     }
}

class HolderGroovy extends HolderJava {
     public ContentGroovy getContent() {
         ContentGroovy    newContent = new ContentGroovy()
         newContent.value = "snarf"

         // doesn't work, throws NoSuchFieldError
         //super.content = newContent

         // works
         content = newContent

         newContent
     }

     public static void main( String[] args ) {
         println( new HolderGroovy().getContent().getValue() )
     }
}
```

Comment: According to the groovy user mailing list, "super" cannot be used for properties. I can't seem to find this referenced in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

seemed to work fine when I pasted the code into GroovyConsole.  Is the Java pre-compiled or compiled with groovyc?

Comment: In the actual case, the Java is compiled via javac and in a .jar, the Groovy is compiled via groovyc and in another .jar. I get the same results when using the eclipse groovy plugin as well, although I think that uses the eclipse JDT compiler for Java and groovyc for Groovy.